# Uncaught TypeError: this.EventDispatcher_initialize is not a function createjs error

Tags: actionscript-3, createjs

i am following a famous book "beginning html5 game development with createjs.pdf " Apress Publication .
Anyhow when i run the codes i get error in my browser console : i updated my createjs hosted lib to latest version 
gs skinner github i found  p.initialize =function is deprecated .
i am not a good programmer. is there any way so that i can fix the error and run the codes of this book. thanks

Uncaught TypeError: this.EventDispatcher_initialize is not a function 
    AssetManager.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: 
here i pasted few lines for 34 to last of function

```
 p.initialize = function () {
        this.EventDispatcher_initialize();
        this.loadManifest = [
            {id:this.EXPLOSION, src:this.assetsPath + 'explosion.mp3'},
            {id:this.SOUNDTRACK, src:this.assetsPath + 'dreamRaid1.mp3'},
            {id:this.GAME_SPRITES_DATA, src:this.assetsPath + 'all.json'},
            {id:this.GAME_SPRITES, src:this.assetsPath + 'all.png'}
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show more of your code? The `this.EventDispatcher_initialize` is used with early inheritance approaches, as well as with the newer `extend/promote` approach.

If you are using the old approach, there should be a line above this one that says:

```
p.EventDispatcher_initialize = p.initialize;
```

This stores the superclass (EventDispatcher) method on the current class prototype first, so you can call it to apply the default functionality. You should also see *something like* this at the top, which sets up the inheritance:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.initialize();
}
var p = MyClass.prototype = new createjs.EventDispatcher();
```

If you are missing any of these steps, your code will not work.

Comment: Lanny sir , i just kept  "beginning html5 game development with createjs.pdf" in webserver xampp and all the code working file . i think if developers run their createjs code from webserver . they can avoid lots of local browser security issue . thanks